# Probability Not Making Sense In A Book Problem

Tags: probability, self-study

This is not homework. This is purely out of edification.

52% of all households have cable service. 84% of all households have multiple TVs. Suppose 45% of all households have cable service and have multiple TVs. A household is randomly selected, what is the probability that they have cable service or do not have multiple TVs?

The answer in the book is .61 and I get .6 (or .5968 more specifically). Multiple answers in the book are like this where it's just a little off. Here is how I went about it.

P(Cable U TVs') = P(Cable) + P(TVs') - P(Cable ∩ TVs')
= .52 + .16 - (.52)*(.16) = .6

Is this correct or is the book doing something to truly get that .61 ?

Comment: ... but it's still self-study, so if you can add the self-study tag, that would be appropriate!

Comment: added it, thank you

Comment: @user158565 - you have done an "and", not an "or", calculation... it's "or do not have multiple TVs".

Comment: @jbowman Yes, I did not pay enough attention to that "or".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the probability of P(Cable ∩ TVs') isn't correct; it would be if cable and TV ownerships were independent, but they aren't.  In this case, we have P(Cable ∩ TVs') = 0.07; we can see that from the fact that 52% of all households have cable service and 45% have both cable and multiple TVs, so 7% must have cable and not have multiple TVs.

$0.52 + 0.16 - 0.07 = 0.61$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now.